# Better way to do `IN` query with Python MySQLdb

Tags: python

When I want to do `IN` query with `MySQLdb`, I write something like

```
ids = [1,2,3,4,5] # in most cases, this is passed in as a parameter
placeholder = ",".join(["%s"] % len(ids))
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM a_table WHERE id IN (%s)" % placeholders,
               ids)
```

It's very cumbersome to repeat this everywhere.

I've read the manual of [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html), but didn't found anything related.

So I wonder how do other people do this? Does MySQLdb provides a better way that's not documented?

Comment: Why do you have `len(ids)`? Should not it be `placeholder = ",".join(ids)`?

Comment: @YevgenYampolskiy I use it to create a string like "%s,%s,%s" in the second line. Later, I insert this string to the `sql` statement, and pass the list `ids` as the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to try [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) (I'm more familiar with Flask-SQLAlchemy, so you might have to change the code slightly), you can simplify the query to something like this:

```
class a_table(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'a_table'
    __table_args__ = {
        'autoload': True,
        'autoload_with': db.engine
    }

ids = [1,2,3,4,5]
results = a_table.query.filter(a_table.id.in_(ids)).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach above seems like the best one since as you know, parameterized values are converted into literals. If you're doing it multiple times, my only (unimpressive) suggestion would be to make a function out of the conversion process. Not ideal, but short of bypassing the built-in sanitization MySQLdb provides, I can't seem to find another way to approach it (not to say there isn't one though). Plus, you've probably thought of this already :)

```
def InQuery(query, vals):
  # Would likely have to be adjusted to handle more complex/compound cases
  return query % ', '.join(['%s'] * len(vals))
```

And then execute the queries like:

```
ids = [1,2,3,4,5]
cursor.execute(InQuery(query, ids), ids)
```

Comment: I think formatting `SQL` statements this way may risk being hacked with SQL injection.

Comment: @Satori.Logic In the first example, yes :) The second example (with the actual query structure) takes advantage of MySQLdb's built-in sanitization of arguments (that I conveniently can't test right now :) ).

Comment: @Satoru.Logic I'm sorry, I see exactly what you're saying now (apologies - should have waited until I could actually vet this first). I'll tinker around for a bit, but I'll delete this if I can't find anything feasible.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help answer my question. In fact, I've already written some `SQL` generating functions like this. Just wondering if `MySQLdb` provides something like `cursor.execute("select * from a_table where id in %s", ids)` ;)

Comment: @Satoru.Logic Ha, sorry I couldn't be of any help. If you happen to find a way to do that, be sure to let me know :) Good luck with everything!

Comment: BTW, do you think the feature I described make sense? Maybe we can help implement it in libraries like https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL.

Comment: @Satoru.Logic I think it does, and as long as the input remained sanitized it seems like it would be useful in those cases. It'd be interesting to think through how to implement it in more complex queries with multiple replacements, but that would be the fun part I imagine :)